Error: server returned an error response: error code 3: execution reverted: revert: Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED
I'm trying to do a swap on pancakeswap V2 with anvil fork and I'm getting revert: Pancake: TRANSFER_FAILED
I'm trying to call this
function doSwap() external payable returns (uint256[] memory) {
            require(msg.value >= 1e18, "Send 1 BNB or more");
            uint256 wbnbAmount = 1e18;
            wbnb.deposit{value: wbnbAmount}();
            wbnb.approve(address(this), wbnbAmount);

            // wbnb.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), wbnbAmount);
            wbnb.approve(address(router), wbnbAmount);

            address[] memory path;
            path = new address[](2);
            path[0] = WBNB;
            path[1] = USDT;

            uint256[] memory amounts = router.swapExactTokensForTokens(wbnbAmount, 0, path, msg.sender, block.timestamp);
            return amounts;
        }

like this

pub fn build_tx(
    to: Address,
    from: Address,
    calldata: Bytes,
    value: U256,
    base_fee: u128,
) -> TransactionRequest {
    TransactionRequest::default()
        .to(to)
        .from(from)
        .with_input(calldata)
        .with_value(value)
        .nonce(0)
        .gas_limit(1000000)
        .max_fee_per_gas(base_fee)
        .max_priority_fee_per_gas(0)
        .build_unsigned()
        .unwrap()
        .into()
}

[...]
    let anvil = Anvil::new().fork(rpc_url).block_time(1_u64).spawn();
    let anvil_provider = ProviderBuilder::new().on_http(anvil.endpoint().parse()?);
    let anvil_provider = Arc::new(anvil_provider);
    let helper_call = PancakeV2SwapExamples::doSwapCall::new(());

    let call_data = PancakeV2SwapExamples::doSwapCall::abi_encode(&helper_call).into();
    let gas_price = anvil_provider.get_gas_price().await?;
    // println!("Gas price {gas_price}");
    let tx = build_tx(*contract.address(), alice, call_data, amount_in, gas_price + 1);

    let result = anvil_provider.call(&tx).await?;
    println!("Swap simulation result: {:?}", result);

i tested this with foundry & it's working
[...] 
    function testDoSwap() external {
        uint256[] memory AmountsOut = pancake.doSwap{value: 1 ether}();

        // for (uint i = 0; i < AmountsOut.length; i++){
        //     console2.log("Output", AmountsOut[i]);
        // }
        console2.log("Amounts:", AmountsOut[0], AmountsOut[1]);
    }

